# Agregar items a un array sin que se dupliquen

Tags: angularjs, arraylist, function

Amigos buen domingo, necesito agregar datos a un Array, estoy haciendo una especie de carrito de compra y estoy en punto en donde necesito agregar a una lista los productos que el cliente final quiere comprar, el modo que utilize es el siguiente:

[image: caca]

```
<div class="col-sm-4 text-right" style="width:90px">
 <h-number value="inicial" min="0" max="10" step="1" change="realizarSuma(co,inicial)"></h-number>
     <div  class="precio">
        ${{co.precio*inicial}}
     </div>
 </div>
```

Esto va así: Mediante un number-picker asigno `value="inicial"` que es `$scope.inicial = 0;`  y este va sumando o restando, en el valor `change="realizarSuma(co,inicial)"` que es como una especie de `ng-change` que reacciona al cambio de los botones + o - le mando `co` que corresponde a un array con toda la info de los caffe disponibles (en este caso manda 3 array) y por ultimo mando el valor `inicial` que es el numero de la cantidad que se solicito.

```
$scope.realizarSuma = function(item,inicial){

  var producto = item.producto;
  var contador = inicial;
  var precio = item.precio; 
  var numerico = item.numerico; //identificador
  var preciototal = precio*contador; //total de compra por producto
  $scope.coffedate = [];

  $scope.coffedate.push({total:preciototal,identificador:numerico})

  console.log($scope.coffedate);
}
```

Lo que hago acá después de pasar los datos a una variable es agregar a un array los datos a medidas que se valla apretando + o - pero el problema es que se remplaza el valor (como se ve en la imagen)y eso no me sirve.

Creo que necesito recibir los datos con una condición, para eso tengo `numerico` que es un valor único de cada producto, entonces he intentado hacer una especie de búsqueda con un `for` al apretar + o - que recorra el for y busque si existe `numerico` y si existe que guarde el ultimo valor.

pero algo hago mal, por favor ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el manejo de arreglos y objetos te recomiendo que uses **[Lodash](https://lodash.com)**, es una excelente librería que se basó en otras como **Underscore** para facilitar esta tarea y hoy en día es utilizada en gran variedad de Frameworks, al igual que es muy mantenida y tiene una excelente documentación.

En cuanto a tú caso lo podrías realizar muy facilmente de la siguiente manera:

```
//Por ejemplo $scope.coffedate es igual a [{ 'id': 1 }, { 'id': 2 }];
$scope.coffedate = $scope.coffedate || []; //Validar que sea un arreglo
var newItem = { 'id': 1 }; //Nuevo elemento a agregar
$scope.coffedate = _.unionBy($scope.coffedate, [newItem], 'id'); //Donde id es el identificador
```

Saludos, Nicholls

Comment: Gracias te pasaste! :)

Answer (score 1):

esto  `$scope.coffedate = [];`

deberia estar arriba- fuera de `$scope.realizarSuma = function(item,inicial){`

**Explicación:**

Pero tu arreglo siempre esta vacía, por que asignas [],`$scope.coffedate = [];`,

luego quieres agregar a tu arreglo un elemento, por lo tanto tu arreglo siempre tendrá un elemento como máximo.

**veremos:**

```
var numerico = item.numerico; //identificador
  var preciototal = precio*contador; //total de compra por producto
  $scope.coffedate = [];//declaracion de tu array vacio

  $scope.coffedate.push({total:preciototal,identificador:numerico})

  console.log($scope.coffedate);
```

Comment: @aldanux edite mi respuesta